# jquery img not loading "scr"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i writing a `JQuery` Code,when user click to Thumbnail,the main Slider change base of data-`img`;
the code work and `img append to main slider bot not showing! and image not load,
in the chrome ispector generated image not Appear like a link,

this is my code:

```
$(function () {
        $('.product-item').click(function () {
            var $img = $(this).find('img').attr('data-img');
            var $slider = '<img scr=' + $img + ' />';
            $($slider).appendTo('.large_image');
        })
    })
```

here is some `html`:

```
<div class="large_image">
  <img src="Images/slider/customer1.jpg" />
 </div>
                <div class="product-thumb">
                    <a href="#" class="span3 product-item">
                        <img src="Images/slider/slide2/thumb/customer_item.jpg" data-img="Images/slider/slide2/webpage1.png" />
                        <span>
                            <img src="Images/pet-ico.png" />
                            sample text
                        </span>
                    </a>
                        <a href="#" class="span3 product-item">
                            <img src="Images/slider/slide2/thumb/customer_item.jpg" />
                            <span>
                                <img src="Images/pet-ico.png" />
                                sample text
                            </span>
                        </a>
```

Comment: `src` stands for "source" (without vowels), not "screen" (or whatever you imagined)

Comment: yeah,i find the problem,thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Attribute of image should be `src` not `scr`.

Answer (score 0):

Hope it helps,

img tag should be,

```
 <img src='imge source'>
```

there is an mistaken in img tag scr instead of src thats why,

```
  $(function () {
    $('.product-item').click(function () {
        var $img = $(this).find('img').attr('data-img');
        var $slider = '<img src=' + $img + ' />';
        $($slider).appendTo('.large_image');
      });
  });
```